# find the lines cross while draw free path using QPainterPath

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter, self-intersection, qpainterpath

I'm implementing the free-form style drawing for drawing  a free path using the mouse press and move  with `Qpainter` [QPainterpath](http://qtdocs.narod.ru/4.1.0/doc/html/qpainterpath.html)

Now i have to detect when exactly the drawn path crossed or intersects with the other. how i can identify when the lines crossed each other at some point and give warning to the user.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt API does not have this capability to tell that if a path composed of different elements intersect in a point or not. You should check it by your self. When the path is finished, compare piece-wise segments of the path using `QPainterPath::​intersects` function. The elements could be accessed via `QPainterPath::​elementAt(int index)`.

Comment: so i have to pass the same painter path as an  argument ..?

Comment: No. That solution was for different paths. There is nothing in API to check intersection of a single path. You should do it on your own. See the updated answer.

Comment: sorry to ask you about it late . QPainterPath::Element repPath = thePath.elementAt(i); returns element . then how i can check the points in it .. ? shall i use polygon instead of it ..?